# Fail on UITableView update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Need your help guys !
I'm going mad on a bug on iOS 9 only.
As you can see below, it is going well on iOS 11

[image: This is working on iOS 11]

At the beginning, i've got 4 cells with a status "Nouveau" for new.
When I click on a "new" cell, the status change to "En attente" (for "waiting").

On iOS 9, everything is fine until the last cell. When I tap on the last "new" cell, it doesn't move to "waiting" and the "new" section is still there. After this, the table view is not getting updates anymore, it is going back to normal when i change to another viewController and go back to the one containing the table view.

I'm using NSFetchedResultsController. Data is good, good number of sections, good number of elements by section, good title.

At the start 1 sections with title "Nouveau" with 4 objects
At the end, 1 sections with title "En attente" with 4 objects

```
extension CRDashboardOrdersViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print( self.fetchResult?.sections?.count ?? 0 )
        return self.fetchResult?.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print( self.fetchResult?.sections?.get(index: section)?.numberOfObjects ?? 0 )
        return self.fetchResult?.sections?.get(index: section)?.numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CRDashboardOrderTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CRDashboardOrderTableViewCell") as! CRDashboardOrderTableViewCell
        let order: Order = self.fetchResult.object(at: indexPath) as! Order

        cell.order = order

        if let selectedIndexPath = self.selectedIndexPath, selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
            self.tableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        }

        return cell
    }
}

extension CRDashboardOrdersViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        print( self.fetchResult?.sections?.get(index: section)?.name ?? "???" )
        return self.fetchResult?.sections?.get(index: section)?.name ?? "???"
    }
}

extension CRDashboardOrdersViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
        func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        }

 func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        print(sectionIndex)
        print(sectionInfo.indexTitle)
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            self.tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            self.tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

  func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .update:
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
            if indexPath == self.selectedIndexPath {
                self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            }
            break
        case .insert:
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
            self.selectedIndexPath = nil
            break
        case .delete:
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
            self.selectedIndexPath = nil
            break
        case .move:
            self.tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
            if indexPath == self.selectedIndexPath {
                self.selectedIndexPath = newIndexPath
            }
            break
        }
    }

 func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a mistake with your cellForRow: and your FetchedResults delegate.

When using a FetchedResultsController, on .update you should not use reloadRows, this causes problems, instead you should have a method which updates a cells model like so:

```
func updateCell(atPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyCell {
        updateCell(withCell: cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}

func updateCell(withCell cell: MyCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let MyModel = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) {
        cell.model = myModel
}
}
```

Then in your delegate .update you call updateCell(AtIndexPath), to update the cells UI.

You should also use this cell configure method in your cellForRow

Comment: Thanks for your response
Sadly, it doesn't résolve the bug :/

Comment: But at the time moveRow is called, i just see that current indexPath is (0,0) and newIndexPath is (0,1), first value of the pair seems to be the section and second seems to be the row.
But it looks like section 0 is not deleted at this moment.
It feels like it should first move cell to indexPath(1,x) and then delete section 0.

I just test and deleteSection is called before moveRow

Comment: instead of using move, try deleting indexPath and inserting newIndexPath, this will then call .update on the newIndexpAth

Comment: Love you man ! Saved my life !
A bit weird but it is working !